# SSIS OnError Handler - getting error "Must declare the scalar variable" - why?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Using SQL Server 2016 and SSIS. I want to log errors in the `OnError` handler in a SQL table called `PackageStatus`.

I add a "Execute SQL Task" to the `OnError` event handler.

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ConnectionType | ADO.NET |
| Connection | MyConnectionName |
| SQLSourceType | Direct Input |
| SQL Statement | INSERT INTO [dbo].PackageStatus ([Date],[Status],[Description]) VALUES (getdate(),'Error',@ErrorDescription) |

In Parameter Mapping, I have:

| Setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Variable Name | System::ErrorDescription |
| Direction | Input |
| Data Type | String |
| Parameter Name | @ErrorDescription |
| Parameter Size | 1000 |

When an error occurs, it triggers the OnEvent handler and then it logs this in sysssislog:

> Executing the query "INSERT INTO [dbo].PackageStatus ([Date],[Status],[..." failed with the following error:
> "Must declare the scalar variable "@ErrorDescription".".
> Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

I don't get why it doesn't see the `@ErrorDescription` when I have it in `ParameterMapping`. What is it looking for here?

Comment: If you are really using ADO.NET then you are doing it correctly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Most SQL connections in SSIS use OLEDB though and require ? as parameter in SQL mapped to a 0 based increment in order of appearance in SQL.

Comment: I do know that OLEDB uses ?, but I inherited this and the connection uses ADO.NET already. Before I go ripping out the ADO.NET connections, I wanted to see why this doesn't work - because it looks to me like it should.